# How to add a new line for every two item?

Tags: tables

Project.tex

```
\sectionTitle{Personal Projects}{\faCodeFork}

\begin{projects}
\project
    {Title}
    {Description}
    {Link}
    {tags} 
\project
    {Title2}
    {Description2}
    {Link2}
    {tags} 
\end{projects}
```

cv.cls

```
\newcommand{\cvtag}[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline]\node[anchor=base,draw=darkGrey!70,rounded corners=0.5ex,inner xsep=1ex,inner ysep =0.55ex,text height=1.3ex,text depth=.25ex]{#1};
}

 % Define the 'projects' environment
 \newenvironment{projects}{%
}{%
  \hfill
  \bigskip
}

% Render an project in the projects environment
% Usage: 
% \projects
  \newcommand\project[4]{
  \hspace{1em}
   \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr(\linewidth/2) - 3em}
    \begin{tabular}{>{}l >{}l}
      \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{#1}}\\
      \multicolumn{2}{l}{#2}\\
      \multicolumn{2}{l} \codeSymbol \href{#3}{#3} \\   
      \footnotesize{\foreach \n in {#4}{\cvtag{\n}}}\\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}%
    }
```

[image: Result]

It works fine for 2 projects, but When I try to add the 3rd project in the Project.tex, the text doesn't go to the next line. How to add a new line for every two item?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet compilable!